# Loading UIViews in the background on application launch

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple iPad application with 5 views.  On the first view, the user is asked to make some selections and set some options.  From this information, the other 4 views are programatically changed after an NSNotification message is sent to them. (i.e controls are added, updated).

My problem is that when the application is first loaded, the user sees View1, but View2, View3, View4 and View5 have never been opened yet, so any changes I make programatically to those views are not done and when the user navigates to them (via the tab bar) for the first time, no changes are shown.

[EDIT: I should point out that the code for making the changes to each view is contained within the ViewController itself, and is executed when the view observes the incoming NSNotification.  When the view is not loaded, it understandably never received the incoming NSNotification.]

Only after the user looks at any of those screens at least once and then goes back to View1 and makes changes, are the other Views updated properly.

I thought I could get around this issue by actively loading Views 2,3,4 and 5 into memory on application start, so that they are ready to begin receiving notifications right away.

Is there an easy way to do this in iOS 5?

Comment: When the other views get instantiated and loaded and right before they are going to appear on screen, couldn't they just get the selection & option changes from the root view (or view 1) and then do whatever customizations they need to do?

Comment: Good points.  I should probably explain a bit more about the app - it is a controller for a MIDI device, so when the user sets the parameters on the first screen, the app begins some MIDI conversations which result in the updating of the other Views in 'real time'.  The MIDI conversations also happen on different threads for performance reasons.  It would be handy if the other views could begin updating/collating as soon as the user selects the options on the first view.

Answer (score 0):

Why do the view changes straight away?

I would store an indicator of the changes needed when the users answers the questions on the first view and then apply the changes on `-viewDidLoad` of each view that needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hezi.  I further explained above that the app is a MIDI controller, and setting the options on the first View will start several MIDI conversations to update the other Views.  When the user goes to the second view for example, he should see about 20 audio IR settings that have been garnered from the MIDI device.  At the moment, he just sees the default settings until he leaves that screen, re-selects the options on the first screen and then returns to the second screen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to load the views into memory, I'd suggest you initialize these views with the options that the user set on the first view. What I usually do in such situations, when I have a global parameters that are used in many places, I create a utility class to keep the data, make it a singleton, then access the shared instance in the *viewDidLoad* in the views that use the data during initialization.